# change variable from goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

I tried to write sample program with 2 goroutines to illustrate race condition. One print `x`, another increment `x`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    x := 0

    go func() {
        for {
            if x%2 == 0 {
                fmt.Println(x)
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            x = x + 1
        }
    }()

    <-time.After(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("final", x)
}
```

But incremental routine do nothing and finally in `x` stays zero. But if incremental routine add `fmt.Println(x)` it starts to increment `x` and program working as expected.

**UPDATE #1:**

Purpose of this simple example is only to illustrate data race issue. I know that reading a shared variable between two goroutines without synchronization is a bad idea. Please stop to point me out to that. My question is why incremental goroutine do nothing here? In my picture of the world is should steadily increment, but the issue should appear in the reading goroutine where result may be not determined, because when reading `x` is one, but when printing `x` may be other.

**UPDATE #2:**

I have another example:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := 0

    go func() {
        last := x
        for {
            current := x
            if last != current {
                last = current
                fmt.Println(last)
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            //<-time.After(1 * time.Second) // if uncomment this row program start do "something"
            x = x + 1
        }
    }()

    <-time.After(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("final", x)
}
```

The example is pretty straightforward. One routine increment counter, other print if changed. This program has undefined behaviour only in the case when writing `x = x+1` and read `current := x`  it is not atomic operation and one thread start read the variable in the middle of writing in the other thread and reading operations will read corrupted value.
But why in this case when uncomment sleep in incremental routine program starts to do something?

Comment: Unsynchronized access to a variable from multiple goroutines where at least one of them is a write is undefined behavior. Do not try to find logic in how this code works, instead use proper synchronization.

Comment: You have data races, so the behavior is not defined. The busy loop with no function calls in the second goroutine is also going to cause problems.

Comment: I wrote this program to illustrate data race, but faced with problem of always zero variable.

Comment: So it’s sounds like it nicely illustrates why you need synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see anything happen because the compiler is smart and optimizes the increment away. Because there is no synchronization, the compiler is effectively presented with this code:

```
x := 0
for { x = x + 1 }
```

Since `x` is never truly read anywhere (only as part of the increment) the compiler is allowed to coalesce multiple increments into one. For instance:

```
x := 0
for { x += 10 }
```

Or perhaps:

```
x := 0
for { x += 1<<64 }
```

Which is the same as:

```
x := 0
for { x = 0 }
```

This is obviously pointless and so the compiler optimizes the whole loop away.

Comment: Why is it not "truly" read anywhere? It reads in another goroutine and at the bottom. I know, it reads with datarace but anyway.

Comment: @abonec, the other reads are not synchronized. That is undefined behavior and therefor the compiler can do whatever it wants.

Comment: It is a strange decision - if you have undefined behavior(unsynchronized access), I add another undefined behavior (cut off part of the program with no explaining)